# DRF serialisation issue: combining django-simple-history and django-polymorphic

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-polymorphic

I am using regular Django models but have now started to incorporate a polymorphic model into my DRF REST API project using `django-polymorphic` and `rest-polymorphic`. I am also using `django-simple-history` to track changes to entries in my database. This all works fine for normal models and polymorphic models without a `HistoricalRecords()` field, but errors when trying to interact with any polymorphic model that has a `HistoricalRecords()` field:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'material_ptr_id' into field.
```

In my serialiser for the polymorphic models, I use the following technique to serialise the `history` field:

```py
class HistoricalRecordField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.DictField()

    def to_representation(self, data):
        return super().to_representation(data.values())


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    history = HistoricalRecordField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('history')
```

Is there a way to exclude the `material_ptr_id` field from being taken into account by the serialiser as it is not part of the parent model but only the child models? Or are there any obvious other mistakes I am making? Thanks for any help with this.